# How to change the widget of a multimedia asset from media browser to multiupload

Tags: 7, media

On Drupal 7 I installed and enabled the multiupload_imagefield_widget
Now I would like to alter the widget type for the news articles from "Media Broswer" to "Multiupload".
I understand that I can add a new field and delete the old one, but I have a lot of previous articles with uploaded images to them.
Or maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: screenhots 
[image: Field]
[image: Widget]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the field widget and change it from media browser to multiupload?
You can change your widget without affecting the other nodes which has already images on it.

hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: I tried, it only has the media browser option.

Comment: However I do see it when adding a new field

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? on your image field and widget?

Comment: try this module. https://www.drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus